# C++ ambigous overload for generic template ostream << operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, ostream, enable-if

This question follows my previous question : [Generic operator<< ostream C++ for stringifiable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487846/generic-operator-ostream-c-for-stringifiable-class) where I would like to implement a generic `<<ostream` operator which would work for any class which owns a `to_str()` method.

I have succeeded checking whether a class implements a `to_str()` method and use `std::cout << stringify(a)` thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190799/2352158). However, I have difficulties writing template `ostream<<` operators to make `std::cout << a` works.

The following test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template<class ...> using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_to_string
: std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_to_string<T, 
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().to_str())>
    >
: std::true_type { };

template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_to_string<T>::value, std::string> 
stringify(T t) { 
    return t.to_str(); 
} 

template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<!has_to_string<T>::value, std::string> 
stringify(T t) { 
    return static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << t).str(); 
} 

// The following does not work
/*
template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_to_string<T>::value, std::ostream&> 
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    os << t.to_str();
    return os;
}

template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<!has_to_string<T>::value, std::ostream&> 
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    os << t;
    return os;
}
*/

struct A {
    int a;
    std::string to_str() const { return std::to_string(a); }
};

struct B {
    std::string b;
    std::string to_str() const { return b; }
};

int main() {
    A a{3};
    B b{"hello"};
    std::cout << stringify(a) << stringify(b) << std::endl;    // This works but I don't want to use stringify
    // std::cout << a << b << std::endl;               // I want this but it does not work
}
```

gives the same error as in the original question. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The version with `!has_to_string<T>::value` produces infinite recursion as `os << t` calls itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an *ambiguous overload for 'operator<<* error when the type is std::string, because the templated version in your code has an equal precedence with the one shipped in the ostream header.

You can check that this is the source of your problem by changing your test program with this:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::string("There is your problem") << std::endl;
}
```

And you shall still see the same error.

To solve the problem, you can add an explicit definition of operator<< that will take precedence over the two conflicting templates.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::string& t) {
    using std::operator<<;
    os << t;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Indeed that worked... Why is there an error then when the type std::string now ? And if possible, can we make a more concise code instead of writing 3 `overloaded operator<<`  ?

Comment: @coincoin Edit in my answer to elaborate on that

Comment: @coincoin I don't know any technique to avoid writing another operator<< overload. Strictly speaking, you shall even consider writing overloads for other kinds of strings (std::wstring, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I start to believe that this search for genericity is somehow dangerous since I change the "standard" behaviour...